# No matching function for 'sort(int [2000], int)'| while sorting array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wanted to sort array in a simple way but I do get this error below. How to deal with that?

`**No matching function for call to 'sort(int [2000], int)'|**`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int v[2000];
    std::sort(v, 2000);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is:

```
std::sort(v, v + 2000);
```

The function takes two iterators, the beginning and end of the range to sort. A pointer is a random-access iterator, so it can be used by a function that expects one. In this case, `v + 2000` points past the end of the array and correctly stands for the end of the range.

Comment: @chris: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

```
std::sort(v, v + 2000);
```

Or

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

The first approach only works with arrays, the latter works with `std::vector`, `std::array` and lot's of other containers.